# window.fetch with specific/different port

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Consider the following code where the relative URL is specified in the `fetch` call. This works fine with the default port.

```
let url = '/api/send'
let response = await window.fetch(url, {
   method: 'POST'
});
```

The `window.fetch` does not allow to specify a port unless the full URL is specified as shown below.

```
let url = 'http://<some_url>:<some_port>/api/send'
let response = await window.fetch(url, {
   method: 'POST'
});
```

Is there a way to change the port dynamically for the fetch calls?

Comment: @RolandStarke That will cause something like this- `http://localhost:3000/:8080`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `window.location.origin` to access current url and then concat a port and path to it.

It would look something like it:

```js
let domain = window.location.origin; //http://someurl.com
let port = 8080;
let url = `${domain}:${port}/api/send`;
let response = await window.fetch(url, {
   method: 'POST'
});
```

Comment: Isn't it similar to simply specifying the full URL?

Comment: It is. What's wrong with specifying a full URL?
Using my method port can be set dynamically. As well as API domain.

Comment: This approach works fine for me tank you, I'm connecting from lan to diferents stations with diferents ip